# Jquery/Mobile navigation problems

Tags: jquery, cordova, navigation

On my startpage i hide everything and then fetch a message from a server. If there is a message the messagepage is shown. But when i go back using Androids back button the app ends (closes) like if i was on the startpage and hit the back button. Why?

Here is the code i use to show the message page (from the startpage):

```
$( '#startpage' ).live( 'pageshow',function()
{   
   //Fetch message and in the ajax success handler:
   $.mobile.changePage('pg/message/message.html',{transition: 'none'});
}
```

I´m using JQuery and PhoneGap.

EDIT: Also the same result if i try to open a "popup" (JQM 1.2). It can´t be closed. It seems that the popup is the "startpage". How is this possible?

Comment: You are using jQuery Mobile?

Comment: If you redirect before show startpage the first page in history is message.html so back button force exit.

Comment: @Flatlineato - But how can i redirect to another page without this happening? Also...this isn´t before show...this is on "pageshow".

Comment: using document.addEventListener("backbutton".... like in the first answare

Answer (score 2):

Juw, PhoneGap's Event API gives you a hook in to a user firing the Android back button.  Check out the code below.  If the user is on `<div data-role="page" id="loginpage">` and hits the back button, he leaves the application, else, he goes back one page.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
    if ($.mobile.activePage.is('#loginpage')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    } else {
        navigator.app.backHistory()
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer. But i was hoping not to involve PhoneGap API in my app. I just use PhoneGap for the "Android container". This should be solved in JQuery. It should be possible.

Comment: I agree with you, it seems like it should be doable w/o PG.  If you ever find a way to do it with w/o PG, I'd like to see your solution.

Comment: right now i will solve it with just putting up a button that the user have to click if they want to view messages. A really bad solution since the message can contain info about a new version. But for right now it will have to do until i find a better way to do it.